# White lines appear in SearchBar when using colored navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar

I am getting multiple white lines when clicking in the SearchBar.

[image]

It is happening when using both a **TabBarController** and  a colored bar **NavigationController**, but

- It works when only using a NavigationController
- It works when both TabBarController and NavigationController but with the default color

[image]

---

I setup the navigation color in the **AppDelegate** using this line of code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor =  UIColor(rgb: 0x0277BD)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

And I setup the UISearchController in my **SearchViewController** using:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup the Search Controller

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Events"
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is a satisfying answer but it looks like an iOS bug, that **might** have something to do with the translucency effect that's added by default to the top bar. The top bar consists of two parts (navigation & search) and it seems like the white line appears on the bottom edge of the navigation part during the slide-up animation. If you add `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` to your `viewDidLoad()` the problem goes away.

[image: Translucent bar]
*Translucent bar*

[image: Opaque bar]
*Opaque bar*

**Why does the white line appear only when you embed the `UINavigationController` in the `UITabBarController`?** No idea :(
The `isTranslucent = false` thing is a workaround at best, but maybe it's enough.

Comment: This problem also appear when you have a toolbar at the bottom (navigationController.toolbar). Disabling translucency helps, but has impact in the UI and scrollview behaviour. It's indeed a bug, which should be reported to Apple by everybody effected by  this issue.

Answer (score 1):

An extremely dirty workaround without giving up translucency, is to add a small 'masking' view:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationController.navigationBar.frame.height, width: navigationController.navigationBar.frame.width, height: 1.0)
let view = UIView(frame: rect)
view.backgroundColor = /* Your matching background color */
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin]
navigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(view)
```

Add this to viewDidAppear as a one time action. This workaround doesn't completely hide  the issue during navigation transitions. This issue is a bug which should be reported to Apple by everybody affected by  this problem.